# inject JS code inside a frame that is inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, inject

I want to inject JavaScript code with a chrome extension, within a frame that is inside an iframe and that inside another iframe.

```
Page
  |-- iframe 1
         |-- iframe2
                |-- frame (no iframe), where I want to inject code
```

This is possible? how?

Thanks!

Comment: I have not solved the problem

Comment: Well basically you'll simply need to repeat the injection a few times, see method 1 in [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: Thank @wOxxOm, but I do not understand how to inject the code several times. I want to inject this code: `Date.prototype.getYear = function(){;return this.getFullYear();}` .... Can you give an example?

Comment: Oh yeah!! Thank @wOxxOm :D ... I've got to work, following the method indicated.

Comment: Oh yeah!! Thank @wOxxOm :D ... I've got to work, following the method indicated: `var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    var s2 = document.createElement('script');
 s2.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
 (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s2);
 s2.onload = function() {
  var s3 = document.createElement('script');
  s3.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
  (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s3);
 };
};`

Comment: stackoverflow will not let me add answers ... :( code will try to hang on another page

Comment: Here you can see the readable solution ;)   [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/AaMc5lZ7vHA/a4BBLysHCAAJ)